# How to Install Gem?

Tags: github, rubygems

I don't know where Gem comes from, but I'm trying to install [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) from GitHub, and it says for start ups you need to install Gem. How do I install it?

I've looked up already on Google and on StackOverflow. The results didn't help at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have Ruby installed in order to use Gem. Depending on which OS you're using depends on the installation for Ruby but here is a [link for windows](https://stackify.com/install-ruby-on-windows-everything-you-need-to-get-going/).